How to add a millis() timer on arduino code
I'm making an arduino code, that has a button that activates a piston and after some seconds the piston returns to its original position.
I can't use delay because it pauses all code, so, I need to use the millis() function
But how?
When I tried to add the millis function, the other variables of my code just crashed, I don't know why?

It would be nice if we could see your code, so we could reason about it.

Why your attempt crashed is a mystery without seeing the code.  It is not even clear what you mean by "variables of my code just crashed".

... also by posting your code we can see how you are handling the button and the actuator so that any answer given could be used directly without you having to adapt a generalised solution.

The general pattern for a non-blocking delay is to poll the timer (millis() in this case), and compare it with some reference starting value to determine elapsed time.
For example:
void loop()
{
    static const unsigned long PISTON_HOLD_MS = 2000 ;
    static unsigned long piston_actuate_time ;
    static bool piston_actuated = false ;

    unsigned long now = millis() ;

    if( !piston_actuated )
    {
        if( button_pressed() )
        {
            piston_actuate() ;
            piston_actuated = true ;
            piston_actuate_time  = now ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( now - piston_actuate_time >= PISTON_HOLD_MS )
        {
            piston_return() ;
            piston_actuated = false ;
        }
    }
}

The single-shot timer can be generalised with a class definition such as:
//  cMillisTimer : Millisecond resolution non-blocking polled timer

class cMillisTimer
{
  public:
    cMillisTimer( unsigned long period_ms ) : m_period(period_ms),
                                              m_ref(0),
                                              m_expired(true)
    {
    }
    
    void start()
    {
      m_ref = millis() ;
      m_expired = false ;
    }
    
    bool expired()
    {
      if( !m_expired )
      {
        m_expired = (millis() - m_ref) >= m_period ;
      }
      
      return m_expired ;
    }
    
  private:
    unsigned long m_period ;
    unsigned long m_ref ;
    bool m_expired ;
} ;

This allows multiple concurrent timers with differing periods.
Then the above example might look like:
// Example
void loop() 
{
    static cMillisTimer piston_hold_timer( 2000 ) ; // Two seconds  
    static bool piston_actuated = false ;

    if( !piston_actuated )
    {
        if( button_pressed() )
        {
            piston_actuate() ;
            piston_actuated = true ;
            piston_hold_timer.start()
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if( piston_hold_timer.expired() )
        {
            piston_return() ;
            piston_actuated = false ;
        }
    }
}


Intro
Based on what you're saying, I believe your implying that you want an async timer. Due to you not providing any specific requirements, I'd use the Async Timer library.
Implementation
Provided here
// Other libraries, dependencies, etc....
#include <AsyncTimer.h>
AsyncTimer timer;

void functionToCall()
{
  Serial.println("Hello world!");
}

timer.setTimeout(functionToCall, 2000);
// "Hello world!" will be printed to the Serial once after 2 seconds

millis()
As mentioned here millis() function that returns a time (A timer from when the Arduino has been started). more details here
Provided you didn't include any code, its hard to say what's making your code crash but either way millis() is generally not the best approach for specific use cases such as things that could stall your code (delays, loops, etc...)
Threads
Again due to the lack of information provided by you its hard to say which one is the best method, however some microcontrollers such as ESP32 among others have multiple threads (kinda like cpu cores) where you can run different code in parallel this can be especially useful when you want to run two different code both utilizing timers in parallel. Information here
Alternative
Timer one Benefits primarily being richer hardware support and optimization
